# Problem of reading data from a website

Tags: java, stream, html-parsing

I write an application, that parse data from boards on the airport sites - Sheremetyevo (http://svo.aero/timetable/today/) and Domodedovo (http://www.domodedovo.ru/ru/main/airindicator/flightnew/).

I create an object URL with the link of the site. Next, I call the method openStream. After that this stream is used with the parser HTMLEditorKit.

With Domodedovo it works pretty good, but with the Sheremetyevo airport program behaves strangely. First, a certain number of launches of the application fails - a stream contains symbols in an unknown encoding, and the length of the text is clearly smaller than content of actual page. Then the unexpected happens - a few successful runs, returning the desired data - then again, a series of setbacks. What does it depend? I can't trace this.

I tried to send specific http-headers through URLConnection, hoping that the whole thing in them, as in the browser everything opens fine. But it did not help. The situation has not changed.

In what may be the problem?

P.S. My English isn't very good, so sorry.

Comment: it might be the character encoding being set incorrectly. this could explain the length of message inconsistencies.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem solved.

All of this was due to the fact that the server is compresses the data when sending it to the application.

The http header that came from server:

```
Request Version: HTTP/1.1 
Response Code: 200 
Date: Mon, 22 Nov 2010 23:43:53 GMT 
Server: Apache/1.3.37 (Unix) mod_deflate/1.0.21 mod_accel/1.0.34 mod_ssl/2.8.28 OpenSSL/0.9.8e rus/PL30.22
Expires: Mon, 22 Nov 2010 23:44:44 GMT
Content-Encoding: gzip <-- !!!
Connection: close
Transfer-Encoding: chunked
```

So, it can be possible to read data if you'll use GZIPInputStream.

May be someone finds all this information helpful for himself.